# Show/Hide kendo-panelbar-item based on routerlink active

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm very new to using Angular and I'm doing pretty good at messing things up and having fun at the same time.

I'm looking for a way to build my kendo-panelbar and to be able to show and hide items in the panel as the users selects them.  I have the router link on the item, and when the user selects items, or lists on the page, then I want the kendo-panelbar-item (s) to show:

```html
<kendo-panelbar-item (stateChange)="onProjectDetailsSelect($event)"  title="Project Details"  >
        <kendo-panelbar-item    title="Job Info" routerLink="/project/projectdetails" ></kendo-panelbar-item>
        <kendo-panelbar-item    title="Photos" routerLink="/project/photos" ></kendo-panelbar-item>
        <kendo-panelbar-item    title="Staffing" routerLink="/project/staffing" ></kendo-panelbar-item>
        <kendo-panelbar-item    title="Look Ahead" routerLink="/project/lookahead" ></kendo-panelbar-item>
      </kendo-panelbar-item>
```

Sorry in advance if I didn't explain this correctly.  Still doing all my crash study on Angular.

In my example above, the user would not see these until I had my variable based on them selecting from a page that is in the router-outlet.  Once I have what I need, I would then need to fire off the action to show and hide kendo-panelbar-item (s)